# Loading google map on button click (Not even loading the CDN before that)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps on my website but it affects the speed of the website on the first load, so what I am trying to do is, load it with a button click.

**Html file**

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

    <script>




        function initMapOnClick() {
            console.log("Second fn")

            var mapContainer = document.getElementById("map-container");
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.setAttribute("id", "map");
            div.setAttribute("style", "height: 500px; width: 100%;")
            // return initMap()
            mapContainer.append(div);

            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.setAttribute("src", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&amp;callback=initMap&amp;libraries=places&amp;v=weekly");
            script.setAttribute("defer", "");
            mapContainer.append(script);




            function initMap() {
                // The location of Uluru
                const dallas = { lat: 31.9686, lng: -99.9018 };
                // The map, centered at Uluru
                const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    zoom: 5,
                    center: { lat: 31.9686, lng: -99.9018 },
                    mapId: 'c75a4e4fbeb204b6'
                });

                var prev_infowindow = false;

                state_listings.listings.forEach((listing) => {

                    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(listing[2][0], listing[2][1]),
                        map: map,
                        url: listing[4],
                    });

                    let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content:
                            "<p>" +
                            `${listing[0]}<br>` +
                            `${listing[1]}<br>` +
                            `<a href="tel: ${listing[3]}">${listing[3]}</a><br>` +
                            `<a href="https://${listing[4]}" target="_blank">${listing[4]}</a>` +
                            "</p>" +
                            `<p>${listing[5]}</p>`,
                    });

                    if (listing[3] != "") {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                            if (prev_infowindow) {
                                prev_infowindow.close();
                            }

                            prev_infowindow = infowindow;

                            infowindow.open({
                                anchor: marker,
                                map,
                                shouldFocus: false,
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });


            }



            document.getElementById("map-image").remove();
            var n = document.createElement('script');
            n.innerHTML = initMap.toString();
            mapContainer.append(n);

            // document.head.appendChild( );

        }


    </script>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map-image" style="position: relative;">
        <img style="position: absolute;"
            src="https://staging-realtestedcbdcom.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/dallas_desktop-2-1024x493.webp"
            alt="">
        <div class="mapModal"
            style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 250px; background-color: wheat; padding: 10px;">
            Do you wish to see the map?
            <button onclick="initMapOnClick(); initMap()">Yes</button>
            <button>No</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="map-container" style="display: block;">

    </div>

</body>
```

I am injecting the script to load the google API and the associated function.

This is what I am trying to do, but it gives me an error saying `VM2003:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at initMap (<anonymous>:5:29) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<button onclick="initMapOnClick(); initMap()">Yes</button>`
with `<button onclick="initMapOnClick();">Yes</button>`

after `mapContainer.append(script);` use `script.onload = initMap;` which will make the `initMap` function to execute once the script is loaded

Comment: I tried that and it did not work for some reason. I still get the same error. Can you perhaps do a js fiddle?

Comment: @VanWilder, [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sakil/aegfkzsx/3/)

Comment: What was I doing wrong? I am very curious, I believe the approach was correct?

Comment: @VanWilder, Your initMap function was not waiting for the api to load, Your approach is correct if you are adding script in html instead of appending using js, button onclick event was calling two functions and the 2nd function i.e. initMap() needs the script which you were appending, The script is taking some time to load..., After using onload event it will wait for the script to load an then call initMap function

Comment: I tried the onLoad as well, but it didn't seem to work at the time, so it had me very confused tbh. Either way, thank you so much!